# Как на CRON запустить BASH скрипт который выведет окно с текстом в Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, cron

Не могу понять почему не работает вывод окна пользователю, если команда по его выводу находится в BASH скрипте, который запускается на CRON.

Содержимое скрипта happy.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
zenity --info --text="Happy birthday!"
```

Команда в crontab

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/sh /home/toorr2p/happy.sh >> /home/toorr2p/happy.log
```

При этом если я команду запускаю просто из консоли zenity --info --text="Happy birthday!" то окно выводится

Или если вызываю скрипт из консоли ./happy.sh то тоже все ок, а вот на cron отказывается работать...

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста!

Comment: В bash скрипте заранее укажите куда выводить окно, для этого надо установить переменную окружения DISPLAY

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотреть help к zenity:

```
$ zenity --help
Использование:
  zenity [ПАРАМЕТР…]
  ...
  --display=DISPLAY                X display to use
```

Итоговая команда:

```
$ zenity --info --display=:1 --text="Happy birthday!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Просмотреть переменные среды введя команду env в консоли, и там увидим DISPLAY и его значение, берем его и прописываем в скрипте так

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:1 zenity --info --text="Happy birthday!"
```